# recents/overview screen swap for launcher swap

Tags: crashes, launcher, android-11, customization, recents-screen

is it possible to swap the default recents screen / overview screen that show up when we click the recents button?

the default view, I believe  is an activity of the default launcher(Quickstep)

after swapping the launcher to another, clicking recents tab dont show anything,

 a second click of the button shows a dialog that says **unfortunately, QuickStep has been stopped**

I guess this is happening because, after swapping the launcher the previous launcher is completely killed/blocked?

### I want to change launcher

#### +

### I want to use recents button too

so, is it possible to swap recents view if we create a launcher app which have a custom activity dedicated for recents view swap?

`or is there any app that exists`

or is it possible to use the default recents view with another launcher [*launcher≠Quickstep*]